# Run time XML creation in c# and saving the data

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, c#-2.0

Trying to create dynamic XML file and save the data to it, however i am able to save the last entry and not all the entries. Any thoughts?

To generate XML file with needed nodes:

### GenerateXML()

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(docNode);

            XmlNode albums = doc.CreateElement("albums");
            doc.AppendChild(albums);

            XmlNode album = doc.CreateElement("album");
            albums.AppendChild(album);

            XmlNode title = doc.CreateElement("title");
            albums.AppendChild(title);

            doc.Save(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\albums.xml");
```

The output from button click gives me either 10 records or 100 records or some number of records:

```
 //album is a class returned by web service
if (Elements.Count > 0)
                {

             string path = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\albums.xml";
                //Read the file stream in read mode
                FileStream READER = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

                System.Xml.XmlDocument albumSpecs = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                albumSpecs.Load(READER);

                FileStream WRITER = null; 

                GenerateXML();

                //Create a FileStream for writing
                WRITER = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);


                XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//albums");
                for (int i = 0; i < ResultsList.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    album = (Album)ResultsList.Items[i]; 
                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                    {
                        node["title"].InnerText = album.Title;

                    }

                }
                //Write the data to the filestream
                doc.Save(WRITER);
            }
```

I get the last entry data in the XML and not all the entries returned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<albums>
  <album />
  <title>She will be loved</title>
</albums>
```

How do i build run time XML based on the # of entries returned?

Comment: You only ever create one set of elements in doc the way your code works right now. You don't iterate the element collection in step with your result collection. You never dispose of your READER or WRITER. You overwrite your document with new output without ever doing anything with the old information that you loaded into albumSpecs. I'd suggest giving your code a good hard look and revising this question. Is this homework?

Comment: -1 Not enough information to figure out what you want

Answer (score 1):

First load already saved xml into `XmlDocument` and then add new elements into it ...

**GenerateXML()**

```
string xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "albums.xml");

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode albums = null;

        if (!File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
        {
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(docNode);
            albums = doc.CreateElement("albums");
            doc.AppendChild(albums);
        }
        else
        {
            doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
            albums = doc.ChildNodes[1];
        }

        XmlNode album = doc.CreateElement("album");
        albums.AppendChild(album);

        XmlNode albumName = doc.CreateElement("name");
        album.AppendChild(albumName);


        XmlNode title = doc.CreateElement("title");
        album.AppendChild(title);

        doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding elements to your XML document ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ResultsList.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                album = (Album)ResultsList.Items[i]; 
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    node["title"].InnerText = album.Title;

                }

            }
```

This sample of code isnt doing much, because you only have one element to iterate on ...

Edit : 
I imagine you want to do something like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < ResultsList.Items.count -1; i++)
    {
         XmlNode child = doc.createElement("Title");
         doc.AppendChild .....
    }
doc.save;
```

Comment: Do you have any inputs on passing data ?

Comment: "Passing data" ? I what way ? You are using an object oriented XML parser, which actually parses it for you. If you add nodes to your document, then save, the changes will be commited. So if you load the document, add nodes, save, you will have added info in your file. And dont see what is bothering you :/